# How to read Korean text file (.xlsx) in R?

Tags: r, excel, unicode

I need help reading Korean characters into R environment.
This one is my file.
[image]

Here is the error

[image]

Comment: [Here is a tutorial](https://rpubs.com/adisarid/R_HebRew) on reading csv and Excel files with Hebrew characters. It might be helpful for your case, since it discusses file encoding issues that may be similar to yours. It would also help if you posted the code you used to read your data, including any packages you loaded.

Comment: When I am trying his suggestions, still I get the error